# How to write conditional statements inside a Makefile in C?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have two C files (myfile1.c and myfile2.c) that do two different tasks. The user has to simply type:
`make program` and after that, if the user types
`./program 25 x.txt y.txt`, I want myfile1.c to run. If the user types `./program 50 x.txt y.txt` I want myfile2.c to run. What should be the approach here?

Comment: C source files don't run. They are source code. Programs run. Please clarify, because it sounds like you need 2 different programs.

Comment: You can have two targets: one for `program1` and one for `program2`, so the user can run either one.

Comment: Makefile is not the correct way to implement this feature. It just assembles the binary, after that, it is not able to check program parameters.

Comment: You can write another C file, `program.c`, containing code that invokes one of the other two modules, depending on the arguments. This could involve building three executable binaries, or one (or two, I suppose), depending on your preferences and some other details you haven't given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the target program to build both files in your Makefile:

```
.PHONY: program

program: myfile1 myfile2
```

then write `program` that executes the right file based on argv[1].  Here is a bash implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "25" ]
then
    suffix=1
elif [ "$1" = "50" ]
then
    suffix2=2
else
    echo error
    exit 1
fi
# validate arguments
# shift?
./myfile$suffix "$@"
```

Usually, you would just write one program (i.e. program.c) that looks at argv[1] to see if it needs to run the code for myfile1 or myfile2.